Custom discount not showing on invoice
I have added a custom discount on order using below code and its working perfectly fine but when create invoice from admin then custom discount not showing.
File: app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/sales.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>

then created the model
File: app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Quote/Address/Total/PrepaidDiscount.php
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total;


class PrepaidDiscount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{

    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    )
    {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $prepaidDiscount = 10;
        if($prepaidDiscount){
            $address             = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
            $label               = 'Prepaid Discount';
            $discountAmount      = $prepaidDiscount;   
            $appliedCartDiscount = 0;
            if($total->getDiscountAmount()) {
                $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
                $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount() + $discountAmount;
                $label               = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
            }    
            
            $total->addTotalAmount($label, -$discountAmount);
            $total->addBaseTotalAmount($label, -$discountAmount);
            
            $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
            $total->setDiscountAmount(-$discountAmount);
            $total->setBaseDiscountAmount(-$discountAmount);

            $quote->setCustomDiscount(-$discountAmount);
            $quote->setSubtotal($quote->getSubtotal() - $discountAmount);
            $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);
            $quote->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount);
            $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);            
        }

        return $this;           
    }
}

But discount not showing while creating the invoice, Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Modify your sales.xml as below to add custom discount in invoice and credit memo and then create respective class to set the discount amount in invoice and credit memo.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
    <section name="order_invoice">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Total\Invoice\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
    </group>
    </section>
    <section name="order_creditmemo">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="prepaiddiscount" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Total\Creditmemo\PrepaidDiscount" sort_order="400"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>

Create Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Total\Invoice\PrepaidDiscount.php with following details
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Total\Invoice;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total\Discount;

class PrepaidDiscount extends Discount
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function collect(
        Invoice $invoice
    )
    {
        parent::collect($invoice);
        $finalDiscount = $invoice->getOrder()->getDiscountAmount();
        $finalDiscountDescription = $invoice->getOrder()->getDiscountDescription();    
        $invoice->setDiscountAmount($finalDiscount);
        $invoice->setBaseDiscountAmount($finalDiscount);
        $invoice->setGrandTotal($order->getGrandTotal());
        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($order->getBaseGrandTotal());
        $invoice->setDiscountDescription($finalDiscountDescription);


        return $this;           
    }

}

Create Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Total\Creditmemo\PrepaidDiscount.php
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Total\Creditmemo;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Config;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Total\Discount;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo;

class PrepaidDiscount extends Discount
{
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $taxConfig;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Config $taxConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->taxConfig = $taxConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($taxConfig, $data);
    }

    public function collect(
        Creditmemo $creditmemo
    )
    {
        parent::collect($creditmemo);

        $finalDiscount = $creditmemo->getOrder()->getDiscountAmount();
        $finalDiscountDescription = $creditmemo->getOrder()->getDiscountDescription();    
        $creditmemo->setDiscountAmount($finalDiscount);
        $creditmemo->setBaseDiscountAmount($finalDiscount);
        $creditmemo->setGrandTotal($creditmemo->getGrandTotal() + $finalDiscount);
        $creditmemo->setBaseGrandTotal($creditmemo->getBaseGrandTotal() + $finalDiscount);
        $creditmemo->setDiscountDescription($finalDiscountDescription);


        return $this;           
    }
}

That's All .. Cheers
